# how to change value based on user input, in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change the output value based on the user input, using angular. I can increment the value, however, when an input changes, the outputed value doesn't change

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" ng-change="myFunc()" ng-model="myValue" />
  <p>You have {{total}} points left.</p>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.myValue = 0;      
      $scope.total = 5;
      $scope.myFunc = function() {
        $scope.total -= $scope.myValue;
      };
    }]);
</script>
```

I want it that when the user, clicks, for instance, backspace, the total goes back to its initial value (which in this example, is 5)

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simplier to do

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myValue" />
<p>You have {{total - myValue}} points left.</p>
<button type="button" ng-click="myFunc()">

<script>
  angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.myValue = 0;      
        $scope.total = 5;

        $scope.myFunc = function() {
            $scope.total-=$scope.myValue;
        };
    }]);
</script>
```

Like this, user can see the value but apply it only with an explicit action

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get back to the initial value, you can check the input length.

```
$scope.myFunc = function() {
    if(!$scope.myValue.length){
        $scope.total = 5; 
    }
    $scope.total-=$scope.myValue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ugmv5od1/

Answer (score 0):

I think in your change function you should have this. Add a scope.initial as the starting value rather than total, so you can go back to it when nothing is in the box.

```
$scope.initial=5;
$scope.myValue=0;      
$scope.total = $scope.initial;

$scope.myFunc = function(){
  $scope.total = $scope.initial - myValue;
}
```